# Как использовать регулярное выражение в РНР

Tags: регулярные-выражения, php

Добрый день. 
У меня есть строка `"<img src="/files/oda/news/stories/35241.jpg" alt="35241" width="650" height="376" />"`
И есть регулярное выражение:

```
\d{3}(?=\"\sheight)
```

рег выражение в нотпад++ находит именно то что мне нужно.
Нужно выполнить поиск по этому выражению в РНР.
В книжка говорят выражени нужно заключать в парные ограничители, в общем вот как я пишу:

```
$test = reg_match("#\d{3}(?=\"\sheight)#i", $val[0], $width);
$test = reg_match("/\d{3}(?=\\"\\sheight)/i", $val[0], $width);
$test = reg_match('|\d{3}(?=\"\sheight)|i', $val[0], $width);
```

Увы результат отрицательный из всех вариантов.
Выполнение скрипта останавливается с ошибкой

> Fatal error: Call to undefined function reg_match() in D:\site\ts.dev\transfersites.php on line 57.

P.S. прошу не брошу не забрасывать тапочками т.к. я еще учусь

Comment: Вы букву `p` забыли :) [preg_match()][1]


  [1]: http://php.net/manual/ru/function.preg-match.php

Comment: нашел я опечатался в названии функции РНР вместо reg_match нужно рreg_match

Comment: @Jerrod А Вам что, собственно, найти надо - высоту(height)?

Answer (score 2):

```
preg_match(
    '/height=\"(?P<height>\\d+)\"/', 
    '<img src="/files/oda/news/stories/35241.jpg" alt="35241" width="650" height="376" />', 
    $match
);

echo ($match['height']);
```

Answer (score 0):

preg_match есть в php! тут интерпретатор тебе сообщает, что нет у него функции reg_match который вызывается у тебя в строке 57 кода.